# Parse array into a record with dissimilar structure

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Given the following JSON:

```json
{
  "data": [
    [1, 15, 12, 16],
    [2, 49, null, 43],
    [3, 53, 82, 31],
    [4, 86, 44, null]
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to parse the inner content of `"data"` into a Haskell list of `Row`, which is defined as:

```hs
data Row = Row {
    rowElementId :: Int,
    rowValues    :: [Maybe Int]
}
```

The trick is that for each row, `rowElementId` is the first value in the sub-array corresponding to that row. The mapping from the above JSON to the record structure would be:

```hs
final = [
  Row { rowElementId = 1, rowValues = [Just 15, Just 12, Just 16] },
  Row { rowElementId = 2, rowValues = [Just 49, Nothing, Just 43] },
  Row { rowElementId = 3, rowValues = [Just 53, Just 82, Just 31] },
  Row { rowElementId = 4, rowValues = [Just 86, Just 44, Nothing] }
]
```

I managed to write the `ToJSON` instance for `Row` which is (exposed here for clarity purposes):

```hs
instance ToJSON Row where
    toJSON (Row eid values) =
        toJSONList $ Just eid : values
```

But the `FromJSON` instance is a bit more cryptic to me. I think I'm on the right track but not quite there yet:

```hs
instance FromJSON Row where
    parseJSON (Array arr) = do
        eid <- head arr
        values <- tail arr
        pure $ Row { rowElementId = eid, rowValues = values }
```

With the code just above, the compiler complains that

```
• Couldn't match type ‘vector-0.12.1.2:Data.Vector.Vector Value’
                 with ‘[aeson-1.5.6.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser EntityId]’
  Expected type: [aeson-1.5.6.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser
                    EntityId]
    Actual type: Array
• In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘arr’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: eid <- head arr
```

In `parseJSON (Array arr)`, how to correctly map the first element of the array into `rowElementId` and the tail of the array to `rowValues`, and then return a well-formed `Row`?

-- EDIT

*I can see that doing `head arr` makes no sense as `arr` is a `Vector Value` and not a `List`. Is it necessary to explicitly import the `vector` package to achieve what I want, or is there another way to do so that doesn't require interacting with Vector directly?*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing the `vector` package and did the following:

```hs
instance FromJSON Row where
    parseJSON (Array arr) = do
        eid :: Int  <- parseJSON $ V.head arr
        values :: V.Vector (Maybe Int) <- mapM parseJSON (V.tail arr)
        pure $ Row eid $ V.toList values
```

I'm not sure if this is the best/cleanest way to do it, though.